# How to fix parse mode & doctype errors in html?

Tags: html, character-encoding, doctype

I tried to validate my html code using w3 validator.
one of the results was:

```
Warning No Character Encoding Found! Falling back to UTF-8.
None of the standards sources gave any information on the character encoding labeling for this document. Without encoding information it is impossible to reliably validate the document. As a fallback solution, the "UTF-8" encoding was used to read the content and attempt to perform the validation, but this is likely to fail for all non-trivial documents.
```

the second error was:

```
Warning Unable to Determine Parse Mode!
    the MIME Media Type (text/html) can be used for XML or SGML document types
    No known Document Type could be detected
    No XML declaration (e.g <?xml version="1.0"?>) could be found at the beginning of the document.
    No XML namespace (e.g <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">) could be found at the root of the document.
```

the third error:

```
Warning No DOCTYPE found! Checking with default HTML 4.01 Transitional Document Type.

No DOCTYPE Declaration could be found or recognized in this document. This generally means that the document is not declaring its Document Type at the top. It can also mean that the DOCTYPE declaration contains a spelling error, or that it is not using the correct syntax.
```

But, when i click on view page source on the website it shows at the beginning:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="http://ijmra.is-best.net/xmlrpc.php" />
<title>my website</title>
```

etc....
How can i correct these errors please?
...
update: source input used by w3 validator for this validation:

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("7efc82a5df893398691d5e53fda9f0d9");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";location.href="http://my-site.net/?ckattempt=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`?

Comment: It's possible that the validator does not see what a browser sees. In the validator, select "more options", and check the "show source" checkbox. Run the validation, and that will allow you to check what the markup is that the validator is seeing.

Comment: @Mike thanks for replying. yes i used it as it's displayed in the page source code.

Comment: But did you make the html capital HTML?

Comment: @Mike no sir, it's: `<!DOCTYPE html>`. i have to make it in capital?

Comment: @Mike i tried it with capital but problem still exist